# Return a COUNT from a WebSQL query in a javaScript function

Tags: javascript, return-value, web-sql

I want to return the number of rows in a particular table in a database in `WebSQL` inside a `javascript` function. Below is my code.

```
function getCustomerCount(){    
    var count = 0;  
    db.transaction(function(tx) {   
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts', [], function(tx, results) {
             count = results.rows.length;   
        });
    });
    return count;
}
```

I am new to `WebSQL` and rather unfamiliar with `javascript` also.
Any suggestions?

Comment: use the SQL count query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use promises, here is an example with the Jquery deferred object

```
function getCustomerCount() {
    //setup the deferred object
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    var count = 0;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts', [], function(tx, results) {
            //resolve the promise passing the count data
            defer.resolve(results.rows.length);
        });
    });

    //return a promise
    return defer.promise();
}

var countPromise = getCustomerCount();

//when the promise is resolved do something with the data
$.when(countPromise).done(function(count) {
    //now use count, could be you call another function that needs to use count,
    exampleThatUsesCount(count);
   //or assign it to another variable, or trigger an event that someone else in you app is    listening for
});


function exampleThatUsesCount(count) {
    //do something that uses count here
}
```

Comment: Why use this method? you are adding complexity that isn't needed!

Comment: I was just showing another example of how to handle async processes  don't see that being worthy of a down vote. Personally I like promises as I find it easier for my code to grow.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
function getCustomerCount(){    
    var count = 0;  
    db.transaction(function(tx) {   
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts', [], function(tx, results) {
             // this function is called when the executeSql is ended
             count = results.rows.length;   
        });
    });
    // This returns always 0!
    return count;
}
```

You have to use callbacks like so:

```
function getCustomerCount( callback ){    
    var count = 0;  
    db.transaction(function(tx) {   
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts', [], function(tx, results) {
             // this function is called when the executeSql is ended
             count = results.rows.length;
             callback( count );   // <-- call the callback when is done   
        });
    });
}
```

And use it like:

```
getCustomerCount( function( count ) {
    // do what you want with the count
    console.log( 'The number of rows is: '+ count );
});
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to remove the return statement in the second example

Comment: The thing is I want to use that count in another location so that I want to return the value. Anything that can be done to return the count?

Comment: it's the easier way to retrieve that number

Comment: Thanx for the time and support; that I wanted to return a value and use it somewhere I will go with jQuery method.

Comment: @Droidy - you can simply call your `exampleThatUsesCount(count);` method instead of the `console.log()`